# Heap Allocation and Call Tree buttons on VMMAP tool Disabled

Tags: vmmap

I understand the Heap Allocations button should allow me to see call stacks, but the button is always disabled (grayed out) no matter what I try. (I used the "Launch and Trace New Process" feature to run my application, but it doesn't help.)

Thanks
Rambabu[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this feature to work you have to start the process under VMMap (using "Select Process" and then "Launch and trace a new process"). It won't work if you attach to a running process.

Here is a screenshot showing how the buttons are active when the process is started with VMMap:
[image]